# Pixelation in iOS4 but not iOS5

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I have an image tag with width attribute in px in my html. Running this html in iPad having IOS4 results in a clear image whereas in IOS5 it looks pixelated. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using a retina display for both tests?

Comment: Is there anything else odd about the html or is it just a plain <img tag?

Comment: <img src="screenshot1.png" style="height:100px;"/>

Comment: Hmmm - how big is screenshop1.png really - is it actually 100px tall?

Answer (score 0):

I chose to follow the naming convention Apple uses in its SDK to target the high-res images by adding the suffix “@2x” to the file-name. So for low-res devices, if the standard icon is “icon.png”, the RD devices would be “icon@2x.png”. To get these into the mix, I added a media query into the css file that targets the Retina Display:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    #home-news a {background-image:url(images/icon@2x.png);}
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I used this query directly in html inside the <style> tag, but it didn't work.